# Can a contract add liquidity to an Uniswap pair as owner?

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider

I am not so familiar with Uniswap but I was wondering if a contract could add liquidity to a pair and be the owner. This is to prevent the developer from removing the liquidity. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes a contract can call Uniswap to add liquidity into any pair. The contract simply needs to provide the required assets for the liquidity. Furthemore, the contract will then own the LP tokens, and therefore only the contract can remove liquidity - remember to add such functionality, otherwise you can never remove that liquidity anymore.

You can look here for an example: https://github.com/safemoonprotocol/Safemoon.sol/blob/a2a1b922b1260b618427183ec8d4475d70cf4daf/Safemoon.sol#L1098

Comment: Thanks! This works great. If I don't set the remove liquidity function, will only users with tokens be able to pull out money from the liquidity? My goal is that only mined tokens can be swapped for eth, and nobody can withdraw liquidity from the pool.

Comment: If you don't add "remove liquidity" functionality in the contract, and you don't add functionality to transfer the LP tokens onwards from the contract, then that liquidity can't be removed. Of course if somebody manually adds liquidity, they can also remove that. If your pair is for tokenA and tokenB, then anyone who wants to trade needs to own either one of these tokens.

Comment: The example contract is helpful. Is it possible to have the same contract to be able to add liquidity also for another external token? I tried to create the addLiquidity2 function for such purpose and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's possible if the contract is using an auto LP function.

Also ask the developer to transfer the ownership and the tokens that are minted in the moment of deployment to you.

If you want to talk more about this, leave me a message: https://twitter.com/polthedev

Comment: Thanks. I mean nobody should be able to remove liquidity, only the contract itself under certain conditions.

Comment: Also you can lock the liquidity for a certain amount of time using DXlock or DeepLock